# Querying through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Step model and an Images model; the association between Steps and Images is that an Image belongs to a Step, and Steps have many images.  I'd like to query steps where it returns all the steps that have more than one image.  How would I do this in the rails console?

I've tried the following:

```
Step.where("images > ? ", 1)
Step.joins(:images).where("image.count > 1")
```

and neither work.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you similiar query from my app so you would excercise your brain a little ;)

```
Activity.joins(:slots).group('activities.id').having('COUNT(activity_id) > 1')
```

Ok, what you should do

```
Step(:images).group('steps.id').having('COUNT(images.step_id) > 1')
```

which is EXACTLY my example but with changed model names.

Comment: Also read some about SQL and relational databases because I see you try to apply object-model logic there.

Comment: thanks for your help.  I don't see how slots is being used in your query?

Comment: I've tried the following: Step.group('images.step_id').having('COUNT(images.id) >1') and I get the error "missing FROM-clause entry for table "images"  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: thanks again, this is what ended up working:
Step.joins(:images).group('steps.id').having('COUNT(images.step_id) > 1')

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?:

```
Step.find(:all, 
          select: "steps.*, count(images.id) as image_count", 
          joins: :images, 
          having: "image_count > 1", 
          group => 'images.step_id')
```

Check [this explanation](http://lukaszwrobel.pl/blog/sql-having-clause-in-rails-activerecord)

Comment: thanks for your help.  I get the error "column image_count does not exist"  I also changed the last line of your sample code to group: 'images.step_id'

Comment: Try deleting the select property (or adding the columns you want to the string) and using `having: "count(images.id) > 1"`